# Can you combine controller list params with Hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have noticed that you can pass "params" straight in to the boilerplate code below:

```
[fooInstanceList: Foo.list(params), fooInstanceTotal: Foo.count()]
```

Is it possible to pass "params" in as part of a Hibernate criteria for example the one below?

```
def c = Foo.createCriteria()
    def results = c {
        not { eq("bar","test") }
    }

    [fooInstanceList: results, fooInstanceTotal: results.size()]
```

I am looking to use the "max" and "offset" params so I can use it for paging for example. I would also like to use the equivalent of count that counts all non-paged results. I think results.size() would only give me paged results, instead of the desired non-paged results. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `params` while using the criteria. I suppose you have a typo of not using `c.list`

```
def c = Foo.createCriteria()
def results = c.list(params) {
    not { eq("bar","test") }
}
```

Assuming `params` has `max` and `offset`.

Criteria returns a [PagedResultList](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/api/grails/orm/PagedResultList.html) where you can get the totalCount from it. So

```
results.totalCount //results.getTotalCount()
```

should give you the total count, although there is always a second query fired to get the total count. In this case Hibernate does that for you instead of you doing it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have also realised I need to count non-paged results. results.size() is going to just give me the paged results size. I have added this point to the original question.