# totalResults and pagination with Grails RestfulController

Tags: rest, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am trying to build a frontend using grails RestfulController based backend. My plain get requests get me the list of all objects. I am able to pass in the regular gomr params like max and sort.

My question is how to get the count of all the objects? I need this to correctly implement the pagination on the frontend.

Comment: These answers can help http://stackoverflow.com/a/22669339/2051952 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/19187138/2051952.

Comment: The two answers you pointed out talk about things in general. I am specifically interested in the GET / request to grails.rest.RestfulController

Comment: Post what you have already tried in your controller.